# deprecated strftime in PHP 8.1

Tags: php, datetime, classes

I saw that strftime is deprecated in PHP 8.1.
I saw I can use a class include in intl but I'm not sure to understand how to use It.

On my site I use this function with the array $datesToConvert{020222, 030222, ...} which means "02 Février 2022"

```
function compareDate($date1, $date2){
        return strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
    }
    usort($datesToConvert, "compareDate");

    //Generate Array titles and Array 
    foreach($datesToConvert as $element){
        $titles[] = "Vidéo du " . strftime('%d', strtotime($element)) . " " . ucfirst(strftime('%B', strtotime($element)));
    }
```

The Output is like "Vidéo du 02 Février"

May I have to rewrite my code in another way ?

Regards.

ps : sorry for my poor english i'm french.

Comment: as for me this question is good on Stackoverflow.com, not on Code Review. Using Google I even found on Stackoverflow: [PHP 8.1: strftime() is deprecated - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930824/php-8-1-strftime-is-deprecated) and also some post (which you can find also in comments on question on stackoverflow) [`strftime` and `gmstrftime` functions are deprecated - PHP 8.1 • PHP.Watch](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/strftime-gmstrftime-deprecated)

Comment: Thank you for the link I will study this solution.

Comment: So is this question off-topic because it does not work as coded?

Comment: If you are going from PHP8.1 and up, this looks simple: https://3v4l.org/XGsCA but I'm not sure if I should post an answer.  I'll wait to hear from more experienced content curators.

Comment: @mickmackusa after reviewing this it seems on-topic; yes deprecated warnings, if not suppressed, could cause things to break (e.g. code using it from via XHR requests) but that doesn't mean this code is broken